# Sum all objects by their key name

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I'd like to Sum all objects by their key name using loop. The key "id" will be delete

```
var arr = [{id:1, "my color":1,"my fruit":4},{id:2,"my color":2,"my fruit":4},etc];

var merged = arr.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
     return {
            "my fruit": previousValue["my fruit"] + currentValue["my fruit"],
            "my color": previousValue["my color"] + currentValue["my color"],
             etc:...
          }
        });
```

I'd like this result

```
result = [{"my color":3},{"my fruit":8},etc];
```

Comment: So, what goes wrong with the provided code? What is the question?

Comment: You can call the function from the post I linked with `sumObjectsByKey(...arr)`

Comment: I don't know it doesn't works for another array. I think the problem is when for some keys  if the value is NaN

Comment: ... or remove the three `...` from the function parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than hard-coding the keys, it would be more flexible if you iterated over all keys in the object *inside* the reduce function and add them to the result, that way the input objects can have arbitrary key/number pairs:

```js
const arr = [{id:1, "my color":1,"my fruit":4},{id:2,"my color":2,"my fruit":4}];
const res = arr.reduce((a, { id, ...rest }) => {
  Object.entries(rest).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    a[key] = (a[key] || 0) + val;
  });
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: And how could I get their percent (value/sum of values) and not their sum ?  like this { "my color": 27, "my fruit": 73 }

Comment: Sum up the `values` of the result, then divide each value by the sum